# Get Week number from a given date when week start on Sunday

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, date, week-number

How to get the correct week number of the year from a given date when my first day of week is Sunday.

For example:

`6 May 2018 - 12 May 2018` is week 18

`13 May 2018 - 19 May 2018` is week 19

I'm trying the following extension method but unable to achieve the desired result. It's giving week **19** and **20** where I expect week **18** and **19** respectively.

```
public static int GetWeekOfYear(this DateTime date)
{
    return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
      date, 
      CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, 
      DayOfWeek.Sunday);
}
```

Comment: Looking at the reference Source for the `GetWeekOfYear([...])` method (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/calendar.cs,5f9cb753162a9563 Line 537) you may be using the method wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CalendarWeekRule Enumeration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendarweekrule(v=vs.110).aspx): Defines different rules for determining the first week of the year.

Previously what you were using:

```
CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek
```

which needed to be replaced with:

```
CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek
```

Because:

[image]

Code Snippet:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var week_test = Convert.ToDateTime("05/06/2018");
    var week_test2 = Convert.ToDateTime("05/13/2018");
    List<DateTime> weekList = new List<DateTime>();
    weekList.Add(week_test);
    weekList.Add(week_test2);
    CultureInfo ciCurr = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
  foreach(var week in weekList)
  {
    int weekNum = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(week, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
    Console.WriteLine(weekNum);
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Demo:

[dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hU9qQS)

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the argument for method

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear()`

`CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek -> CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek`

> as per Document for `FirstFullWeek` - Indicates that the first week of the year begins on the first occurrence of the designated first day of the week on or after the first day of the year.

like this

```
public static int GetWeekOfYear(DateTime date)
{
    return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
}
```